# Statistic chart in Excel: why there is one bin for the "Overflow"?

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have this "Statistic Chart" plotted in Excel, in which I set 25 as the "Overflow bin". But why there is a designated bin at 25 (highlighted in red square)? How to remove this? I just want to show all the values larger than 25 in the last bin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set 8 for Number of bins, -10 for Underflow bin like the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBUsc.jpg)?

Comment: yes, it works! You are so clever! can you post your answer, and better explain the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's my pleasure.

In fact, the settings I suggest are based on your first picture.

In addition to the bin of (25,25], there are 8 bins as necessary. But on your second picture, there is 9, so we need to modify the number of bins.

Besides, Underflow bin is to define a threshold for creating bins. Any value below the number to set here will be placed into a kind of “all other” bin. The first bin is between -10 and -5, there is no object less than -10, so we do not need the -16 for Underflow bin, just change it to be -10.

Hope it could be clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1) But I still do not understand, why the (25, 25] was showing there. 2) The "Underflow" was unchecked, so I think it means do not set lower bound.